# How to configure httpd.conf for https migration

Tags: apache, https, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

How to set up httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example.com/"
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /home/thisisme/4b0aa83ea92071ef.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/thisisme/SevenPointTwo2015.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/thisisme/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
    ErrorLog "/var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/html/example.com/logs/custom.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this enough.?
Will I be able to access image files, css files and javascripts.?
Do I need to append anything else.?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem. I had revoke the SSL Layer for certain folders.